# using rlogin with ipv6 address

Tags: kali-linux, ipv6

I am trying to connect to the remote host via rlogin

```
rlogin -l root -p 513 fe80::cccc:1f%eth0
```

But I am getting the message:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

What should I do? Is this the correct way?

Comment: Have you considered `ssh` instead of `rlogin`. `rlogin` is not secure. And Deban (or one of many other distros) instead of Kali. Kali is not for beginners, and has little to offer that other distro don't have.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `rlogin` points to `ssh` by default on all Debian-like distros (most probably including Kali too).

Comment: @mosvy but just in case: If you use `rlogin`, then one day it points to the wrong place, then it is your fault.

Comment: `ssh` too can point to wrong place. For the OP's error: I suggest they run ssh/rlogin with `-vvv`: I suspect that there may be something else than a ssh server listening on port 513.

Comment: 513 is the desginated port for `rlogin` service, while the error message shows that the OP is using `ssh`

Answer (score 1):

Since your `rlogin` is linked to `ssh`, you should be able to connect by dropping the port specification in the command and allowing the client to choose the default port (22):

```
rlogin -l root fe80::cccc:1f%eth0
```

although since the client is really ssh, you could just skip past the indirection:

```
ssh -l root fe80::cccc:1f%eth0
```

If you *really* want to connect via rlogin, you would again drop the port specification from the command line as per the first example, but you'd need to ensure that you were using an actual `rlogin` client and that the remote machine had an `rlogin` server listening on `tcp/513`.